# Finding missing strings in Android

Tags: android, string, android-resources

I am cleaning and rebuilding some of my project, and some phrases gets deleted from `values.xml`. Is there a way to detect these phrases which are deleted and get some kind of error in code before building.

Because currently I simply get crash in certain areas of app there phrases are missing and are being accessed by old code.

For example phrase `partsone` is not found in `values` anymore.

But code

```
Title.setText(context.getString(R.string.partsone));
```

looks good in eclipse and builds. Only crashes at runtime...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to use lint. It has a check for missing strings and several other analyse tools on board.

http://tools.android.com/tips/lint

More informations how to use Lint with Eclipse can be found at http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/improving-w-lint.html

Take care:

you will need the eclipse ADT Plugin installed to get lint working (for free) with eclipse. You can get the ADT Plugin at http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html

After it is installed you can see the lint dialog at

```
Window > Show View > Other > Android > Lint Warnings.
```